# iOS keyboard issues with Gboard on Angular PWA installed to home screen

Tags: ios, angular, progressive-web-apps, gboard

I have an Angular PWA that when I install to home screen on my iPhone6S I end up with Gboard keyboard issues that has been set up as default. The keyboard just does not respond, not even to a single key tap. I cannot see a specific sequence that causes this issues, but at times the only thing that will clear it is restarting the phone. Would really appreciate any insight into this. Cheers.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/55738553/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)